# How should I programmatically customize the "My Profile" page (person.aspx)?

Tags: visual-studio, feature, best-practices, my-profile

I am trying to customize the "my profile" page (person.aspx, "my site host" site collection) in SharePoint 2010. For example, I  would like to:

- Add/delete some webparts
- Delete links from top navigation bar
- Hide quick launch bar

I know I could do this with the Sharepoint UI or Sharepoint Designer, but I would like to have a Visual Studio Solution to do this. It is important that the solution can be (easily) updated in the future and allow me to customize other profile pages.

Would any of the following work?

1. A Feature in VS and add the code to customize the page in the "featureactived method"
2. Feature stapling
3. Import person.aspx or a site definition in VS and then directly customize it

What would be the best practice?

Comment: nobody ? hmm... :-(

Comment: I am also searching for the same. Did you get the answere? How did you do it?
Please share.
Thanks
Khushi

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, deploying a solution with your code in a feature is always the way to go.

You'll need to use feature stapling to do more advanced look and feel changes.

[Customizing My Sites in Microsoft SharePoint 2010](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/spsocial/customizing-my-sites-in-microsoft-sharepoint-2010)

Answer (score 0):

I also would use **feature stapling** so that I didn't risk introducting a change to the master Microsoft-owned pages that could break when the next service pack or update is applied. I would avoid editing those pages directly if at all possible.

The link provided by @kit-menke has useful tips on how to make these types of edits.